# Codec issues in pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, codec

I have two text files:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/idk7k5qv2mp3d4p/bad.txt?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/x27fngacngaglyy/good.txt?dl=0

Hex editor shows bad.txt begins: "FF FE 53 00 79" and Notepad++ reports the file is UCS-2 LE BOM. I believe utf_16_le should decode this, but the following code errors with UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x53 in position 2: truncated data:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("good.txt")
df2 = pd.read_csv("bad.txt", encoding="utf_16_le")
```

I have tried every codec I can find, but cannot get pandas to read bad.txt. I have many files like this to read in an automated context. Two questions:

1. Is something "wrong" with bad.txt? Is the program generating the file somehow mishandling the file?
2. How can I read this into a pandas df? If necessary, can I convert the file with python code? The data seems to be fine since many other programs (text editors, excel, etc.) can interpret it, but how do I get pandas to play nicely?

Comment: Works for me with encoding `utf_16_le` or `utf-16`.  Pandas 0.20.1, Python 3.5.3.  What versions are you using?

Comment: crap. pandas 0.18. update fixed it. Thank you! Write comment as answer if you wish and I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: That's good.  After a while you'll be able to accept your own answer.  :)

Comment: That's quite philosophical... :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Pandas 0.20 handles this file with utf-16 codec, as expected. Thank you for those who looked at it.